# page will not align center

Tags: html, css, center, alignment

I have got a css problem.

http://www.luukratief-design.nl/dump/parallax/index.html

I cant get this page to align center. 
Before i get the answer to use "text-align: center;" on the body, i already did.

The page 100% validates (CSS and HTML).

Please help, never had this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the left and right margins of the `#wrapper` div to `auto`

```
#wrapper{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! dont see why it is necessary, but it works like a charm, great help!

Answer (score 2):

to align a page in the center you can place all the content of the page inside a container div and set these css properties

```
body
{
    text-align: center; //for ie 6

}
#main_wrapper
{
    text-align: left;
    width: 1000px; //any width you want
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

here main wrapper is the div that contains all the content

Answer (score 1):

add this to you wrapper:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this css to align to center:

```
<style>
  #your_div_id {margin:0px auto;}
</style>
```